# Xamarin.Auth: Limit login session to application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, oauth-2.0, xamarin.auth

I am currently working with Xamarin.Auth on Xamarin.Forms (Android/iOS). I am implementing a "Login with Google+" feature, and it works, but not quite as I expect. Every time a user logs in, the log in session also happens on the Native browser. Is there a way to limit it to only the application? I.e. the user's login session is only valid in the application. A lot of applications have this.

What I have tried to do is to follow this [tutorial](https://timothelariviere.com/2017/09/01/authenticate-users-through-google-with-xamarin-auth/). In the official [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/oauth/#Presenting_the_Sign-In_User_Interface), they say one has to use Xamarin.Auth.Presenter. Is that the solution? I have tried to read about it, but I can't see why that should do the work.

This is how I do it:

I have created a "fake" contentpage in order to start the authentication process, and in each platform I handle the code behind with custom renderers. So far I have only tested it on Android:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(GoogleLoginPage), typeof(GoogleLoginPageRenderer))]
    {
    class GoogleLoginPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public GoogleLoginPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var activity = Context as Activity;
            activity.StartActivity(GooglePlusSingleton.Instance.OAuthSettings.GetUI(activity));

            GooglePlusSingleton.Instance.OAuthSettings.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) => {
                if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Virker");
                    GooglePlusSingleton.Instance.SaveToken(eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"]);
                    GooglePlusSingleton.Instance.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Virker ikke");
                    GooglePlusSingleton.Instance.FailedLoginAction.Invoke();
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

As I mentioned before, the login works, but when I login through the application it also logs in through my Native browser.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Chrome CustomTabs = `Shared cookie jar and permissions model so users don't have to log in to sites they are already connected to, or re-grant permissions they have already granted.` https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: Yes, I am using that :) However, I want to remove the the shared cookie jar i.e.  users have to log in to sites they are already connected to, or re-grant permissions they have already granted

Comment: They would need to go into Chrome's setting and via `Manage Space` and clear all data or manually clear a sites storage one by one via `Manage`

Comment: Maybe I haven't explained myself well. The login works through the app, so is there a way to disable the shared cokkie jar programatically? The users shouldn't do it.

Comment: No, you can not. You should look at using the Google(+) native APIs for sign in instead.